# How can validate good use cases for a technology?

Tags: tech-industry, research

Lately, I have come across to several unusual scenarios where a piece of technology is used for something that is not the intended use. Sometimes, I got involved in one of these scenarios when the technology stack, which is defined by the developer in charge, has some problem and I need to advise on a solution.

The problem is that is very difficult to find evidence that the use of that technology might not be correct since the technology itself is brilliant and can be used in different ways.

How could I back my concerns when I don't find any resource against or in favour?

The most recent example is using a PWA framework(Vue.js)  to build the front-end for building a website that does not intend to have a mobile application but accessed for mobile devices.

Comment: Welcome. Your question is very abstract. Maybe you could [edit] it to give an example or two, or ask another more specific question.

Comment: `The problem is that is very difficult to find evidence that the use of that technology might not be correct since the technology itself is brilliant and can be used for other purposes.` - This statement contradicts your question.

Comment: Focus on the money. Can the off-label use bring in serious revenue? Potentially more than the current official use of the technology? If yes, you might consider pivoting. If not, stay on task. Do not try to please everybody in your audience. Focus on the money, not your ego. In any case, more details would be helpful. If you give us an abstract question, we can only provide you with a vague abstract answer.

Comment: Thank you @O.Jones, I have enhanced the question.

Comment: @joeqwerty. It does, but my point is that you shouldn't use a piece of technology just because it has the capability. A dumb example: you wouldn't use an IDE to run a production server just because you think is bright to use Hotswap for quick releases. You could do it but that's just wrong. (How could I back that up?)

Comment: @StephanBranczyk, I appreciate your answer, I role's responsibilities have been growing, and I have detected patterns on people keen to use new stuff so they just do, and that overcomplicate scenarios because they build 90% of the solution and then they realize that the remaining 10% is too hard to solve. Sometimes they just solve something and a different problem comes for the back of it. I am just trying to prevent those scenarios (maybe I shouldn't?)

Comment: why do you need to advise a solution not the subject expert in charge?

Comment: What do you mean with the expert in Charge? The developer who works in the project, explore the feasibility of the technology and get to decide on in. By the time I get involved in the project, It is difficult to challenge that decision because some progress has been made

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that the analysis has to be done for each case separately. There are many factors which can influence the final decision.

The best example of an abused tool are the spreadsheet applications (including MS Excel). Although they were created for a very specific reason, and they do best for that, they are actually used for a myriad of other purposes. Even when dedicated very efficient tools are available on the market.

Some criteria to have in mind when choosing a tool:

- is it able to actually do the job?
- is it simple enough, to ensure easy use?
- is it cheap enough?
- is it free? sometimes, free is welcome, some other times free is abhorred;
- can it actually hurt the project / activity / business if used incorrectly?
- is is possible to implement safeguards against improper use?
- etc.

Sometimes, even apparently insignificant details can matter a lot during a careful analysis.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I think it would work if I would have participated in the decision making process. The thing is that I noticed  the issue a lot later and I think that at this point the answer to my problem is "Too late mate. Let it be"

Comment: Yes, sometimes the "Let it be!" strategy is the best. Fighting lost wars is useless.